# ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED when deploying using msdeploy command

Tags: iis, certificate, azure-devops, web-deployment, msdeploy

I have created a clone of a server and it is giving me this error when I am deploying the code through VSTS:

Error Code: ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED
2018-04-16T08:15:26.6941482Z More Information: Connected to the remote computer ("abc.com") using the specified process ("Web Management Service"), but could not verify the serverΓÇÖs certificate. If you trust the server, connect again and allow untrusted certificates.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED.
2018-04-16T08:15:26.6942141Z Error: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
2018-04-16T08:15:26.6942420Z Error: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
2018-04-16T08:15:26.6942538Z Error count: 1.

Certificates are properly installed and valid.

Comment: Where does your server located? And can you share the detail logs by setting `system.debug` variable as `true`?

Comment: Try to deploy the app through [WinRM IIS Web app Deployment task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploy/README_IISAppDeploy.md) and check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved. The issue was that the routing is not configured properly and it was trying to deploy on another server(say server 2) form which it was cloned. That's why I was getting the invalid certificate issue for server 1 because it was checking the certificates of server 2.
                                                     **Thank you all for your help. I appreciate it :)**

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-allowUntrusted` option to MSDeploy command line

Comment: After adding -allowuntrusted , getting this error : Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST

Comment: @Twinkle Is the site existing?

Comment: Can you @twinkle display your command line, masking any sensitive data please?

Comment: @GiulioVian: command:-source:iisApp="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Sitename Portal Build CI-Validation\drop\src\Sitename.Web\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish\" -dest:iisApp="Sitename",ComputerName="https://hostname:8172/msdeploy.axd? site=Sitename",UserName="username",Password="password",IncludeAcls="False",AuthType="Basic" -verb:sync -enablerule:AppOffline -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:20 -setParamFile="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Sitename Portal Build CI-Validation\drop\src\Sitename.Web\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish\wwwroot\parameters\parametersValidation.xml"

Comment: @Twinkle What's the result if you call the command manually? (Replace  variable)

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT: It gives me the same error:  ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED I have tried everything on the server related to the certificates, web deployment service.